# 2 django sites on 1 apache virtual host with django login

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-python

I have 2 sites, both require login ( I'm using the django provided django.contrib.auth.views.login).  When I enter http:// url /siteb , I am redirected to accounts/login and siteb is taken out of the URL creating http:// url /accounts/login.  But then I get an error "The requested URL /accounts/login was not found on server"

If I remove the login requirement and go directly to a page I can click around the site without problem (http:// url /siteb/faqa)  If I have only one site in apache and use < Location "/" > I don't have a problem logging in and navigating. My issue is when I have 2 sites, both with the login redirect

(Django 1.2.1, Apache 2.2.14, Python 2.6, mod_python just because that's what I was told to use)

> < VirtualHost *>
>
> ```
>   ServerName name  
>   DocumentRoot /etc/sites  
> < Location "/siteb">  
>             SetHandler python-program  
>             PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython  
>             PythonPath "['/etc/sites', '/etc/sites/siteb'] + sys.path"  
>             PythonOption django.root /siteb  
>             SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE siteb.settings  
>             PythonInterpreter siteb  
>             PythonDebug on  
>     < /Location>  
>     < Location "/sitea">  
>             SetHandler python-program  
>             PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython    
>             PythonPath "['/etc/sites', '/etc/sites/sitea'] + sys.path"    
>             PythonOption django.root /sitea  
>             SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE sitea.settings  
>             PythonInterpreter sitea    
>             PythonDebug on  
>     < /Location>
> ```
>
> < /VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

All of the urls should be prefixed with /sitea/ or /siteb/

Django generally assumes that it is installed at the root of the website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  What do you mean "urls should be prefixed with /sitea/"? Do you mean when I do an HttpResponseRedirect /sitea should be included? Do you mean in the urls.py urlpatterns all urls should have /sitea included?

Comment: I mean both. Like I said django normally expects to be at / not at /something